# How to plot labels on top of pie charts --> Why pie chart disappears when adding label string?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, percentage

I do not understand why when adding the labels of the string on the pie chart, the pie chart compresses/disappears. Why is this possible and how can I change it?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
df <- data.frame('Fruit'=c("Apple", "Apple","Pear","Pear", "Coconut","Coconut"), 'Colour'=c("Blue", "Yellow","Blue", "Yellow","Blue", "Yellow"), 'Abundance'=c(57.81,42.19,59.89,40.11,41.73,58.27))

ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = Abundance, fill = Colour)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1, position = position_fill(), colour="black") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y")+
  facet_wrap(~ Fruit, ncol=3)+
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete= TRUE)+
geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(Abundance == 0, "", paste0(Abundance, "%"))),
          position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

This is before adding the `geom_text`:

[image]

And this is once I add the `geom_text`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar` with `stat="identity"` and `position=position_fill()` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = Abundance, fill = Colour)) + 
  geom_col(colour = 'black') +
  coord_polar(theta = "y")+
  facet_wrap(~ Fruit, ncol=3)+
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete= TRUE)+
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(Abundance == 0, "", paste0(Abundance, "%"))),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If you want to use `geom_bar` you should use `position = "position_stack()` instead of `position_fill` since your bars are actually stacked like this:

```
geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_stack())
```

Comment: Thanks @Quinten , that worked, is it possible to add color "white" to the values that are in a purple slice to be able to see them better?